# Channel or Canal?

Tags: civil-engineering, terminology, water-resources

This is about navigable or irrigation water ways.

Examples:

1. Navigable channel or navigable canal? (it is about approach water ways to sea ports, or artificial inland water ways).
2. Channel dredging or canal dredging? (it is about navigable water ways).
3. Irrigation channel or irrigation canal? (it is about water ways within open irrigation systems).
4. Drainage canal or drainage channel? (it is about drainage water ways cut in earth).

Comment: in my native language (Russian), the terms canal and channel have the same translation in dictionaries.

Comment: in navagation context a canal is a man made waterway, a channel is an artificially deepened portion of a natural waterway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I thought this would be easily answerable by looking at English dictionaries. But they're not as useful as I'd hoped.

**[Channel](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/channel?s=t)**:

> 1. the bed of a stream, river, or other waterway.
> 2. *Nautical.* a navigable route between two bodies of water.
> 3. the deeper part of a waterway.

**[Canal](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/canal?s=t)**:

> 1. an artificial waterway for navigation, irrigation, etc.
> 2. a long narrow arm of the sea penetrating far inland.

Well, I disagree with both of those.

- A sea is not a "waterway", but a deeper, navigable route through it is definitely a channel; possibly this is covered by definition 2? I'm not sure.
- A long narrow arm of the sea penetrating far inland is a river, not a canal. In my experience (and, to be honest, backed up by the "British dictionary" further down the webpage), a canal can *only* be a manmade / artificial waterway.

So, to answer your questions:

1. Navigable channel or navigable canal? (it is about approach water ways to sea ports, or artificial inland water ways). *If a navigable path through the sea it can only be a channel. If a navigable artificial inland waterway, it can be a navigable canal, but you can also call it a navigable channel. Navigable channel would therefore always be acceptable for this.*
2. Channel dredging or canal dredging? (it is about navigable water ways). *As above*
3. Irrigation channel or irrigation canal? (it is about water ways within open irrigation systems). *Either is acceptable, assuming it is man-made (seems likely for an irrigation system). Personally, I would lean towards "irrigation channel". According to [google ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=irrigation%20channel%2C%20irrigation%20canal%20&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1980&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t4%3B%2Cirrigation%20channel%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Birrigation%20channel%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BIrrigation%20channel%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BIrrigation%20Channel%3B%2Cc0%3B.t4%3B%2Cirrigation%20canal%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Birrigation%20canal%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BIrrigation%20Canal%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BIrrigation%20canal%3B%2Cc0), "irrigation canal" is more common, but not massively so.*
4. Drainage canal or drainage channel? (it is about drainage water ways cut in earth). *This is similar to the irrigation question above. Again, I would lean towards "channel". For this one, [google ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=drainage%20channel%2Cdrainage%20canal&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1980&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t4%3B%2Cdrainage%20channel%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bdrainage%20channel%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BDrainage%20channel%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BDrainage%20Channel%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BDRAINAGE%20CHANNEL%3B%2Cc0%3B.t4%3B%2Cdrainage%20canal%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bdrainage%20canal%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BDrainage%20Canal%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BDrainage%20canal%3B%2Cc0) agrees with me (just!).*

Comment: +1 for _"In my experience ....for a canal can only be a manmade / artificial waterway."_  That matches my experiences as a hydraulic engineer in the U.S.